# Laravel/Lumen Class Not Found: LoadEnvironmentVariables

Tags: laravel, lumen

I've made a fresh Laravel/Lumen install with composer but when a try to run it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\lumen\bootstrap\app.php:5
```

so I try to find the `LoadEnvironmentVariables` class in all the Lumen files but it only appear in the `app.php` itselft, how can I solve it?

Comment: This is the php file https://github.com/laravel/lumen/blob/master/bootstrap/app.php

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes, by using Laravel instead of Lumen

Comment: Still using lumen but I solved.. don't know exactly how. The mentioned class was there, but I got rid of the vendor folder a couple of times, cleared cache, reinstalled dependencies and the issue went away :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to use regular Laravel instead of Lumen.

*btw Taylor Otwell (Laravel's creator) recommends no using Lumen anymore*

*source:*

> https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1441101127496323080
> https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1212832185830510592
> https://twitter.com/taylorotwell/status/1212833250483277824

Comment: Also: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/10.x#:~:text=For%20this%20reason%2C%20along%20with,beginning%20new%20projects%20with%20Laravel.
On the offical Laravel site: "Note: In the years since releasing Lumen, PHP has made a variety of wonderful performance improvements. For this reason, along with the availability of Laravel Octane, we no longer recommend that you begin new projects with Lumen. Instead, we recommend always beginning new projects with Laravel."

Answer (score 2):

I've facing the same issue, in my case when finish update my Lumen to the server, i'am replacing my .env app and then the Error is appear. The solution that work for me is to re-install dependncies using this command:

```
composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

After struggling half a day, I found that an error_log in vendor/autoload.php did not appear.

The problem was solved by restarting Apache! Some cache somehow prevented the new autoload.php to be imported.

I hope this can help and save time to somebody else.